# Why does a javascript object property assignment via the dot notation NOT trigger a setter defined for that property?

Tags: javascript

Any Javascript ninjas or people who have read ECMA-262 5th care to explain the following behavior?

```
var obj = {
  p: {},
  set prop(val){
    for (var key in val){
      this.p[key] = "Set: " + val[key];
    }
  },
  get prop(){
    return this.p;
  }
}

obj.prop = {  // Assignment triggers setter
  foo: "Foo"
}

obj.prop.bar = "Bar";  // Assignment does not trigger setter

console.log(obj.prop.foo); // Set: Foo
console.log(obj.prop.bar); // Bar
```

I found the above behavior a bit confusing because I expected the two assignment notations to be functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental difference is that `obj.prop = foo` is changing what the `prop` property of `obj` references, while `obj.prop.bar = "Bar"` is merely changing some property of the object to which `obj.prop` refers but not changing the reference itself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my answer. Much appreciated. You are, of course, quite correct. :-)

Comment: Your answer clarifies that the two assignment notations are not functionally equivalent. If I understand correctly, `obj.prop.bar = "Bar"` **assumes** `obj.prop` is an initialized object and attempts to assign the property `bar` to it, whereas `obj.prop = {foo: "Foo"}` **defines** `obj.prop` as an initialized object with the property `foo`.

Comment: Not really. There's only one assignment notation in play. What `obj.prop.bar = "Bar"` is to first get the object that `obj.prop` references (using a getter if one is defined), and then sets the `bar` property of that object (if that object had a setter for the `bar` property, that setter would be called). `obj.prop = {foo: "Foo"}` is doing exactly the same thing except that `obj` is a variable reference that needs no resolution.